# Proteção de dados contra alterações no MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

Eu preciso proteger os dados de um sistema contra alterações na base de dados.

É um sistema que utiliza transações financeiras.  Preciso de um mecanismo que impeça que alguém com acesso ao banco de dados faca alterações nos campos por exemplo nos valores dos lançamentos.

O sistema foi desenvolvido em .NET CORE 3.1 com Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Veja se é isso que está procurando [Using Roles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html)

Comment: O que eu preciso é de algum tipo de criptografia que invalide o registro caso alguém altere os valores no banco de dados. Por exemplo: através do sistema é criado um lançamento com valor de R$100. Se alguém alterar o registro no banco de dados para R$ 1.000 quero que seja possível verificar esta alteração através do sistema.

Comment: [InnoDB Data-at-Rest Encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-data-encryption.html)

Comment: Augusto vc tem algum exemplo de como implementar Data-at-Rest com EF core?